# Convert multiple lists to dataframe python

Tags: python, list, pandas

I want to put list in dataframe, my code is,

```
webpage_urls = ["https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&organization=departmentofagriculturefisheriesandforestry&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=commonwealthscientificandindustrialresearchorganisation&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=bureauofmeteorology&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&organization=tasmanianmuseumandartgallery&_groups_limit=0",
                 "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=department-of-industry&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&groups=sciences&_groups_limit=0"]

    for i in webpage_urls:
        wiki2 = i
        page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

        # fetching organisations

        data3 = soup.find_all('li', class_="nav-item active")

        lobbying1 = []
        for element in data3:
            lobbying1.append(element.span.get_text())
        print(lobbying1)

        df = pd.DataFrame({'Organisation':lobbying1})
```

My above code is giving output as:

```
['Reserve Bank of Aus... (24)', 'Business Support an... (24)']
['Department of Finance (16)', 'Business Support an... (16)']
['Department of Agric... (13)', 'Business Support an... (13)']...so on
```

Which is multiple lists, not a nested one and I am getting data frame as follows only:

```
   Organisation
0  Australian Charitie... (1)
1  Business Support an... (1)
```

I want output as two columns first element of list in column in column 1 and second element of list in column 2, and I want all entries:

```
Organisation            Groups
Australian Cha...      Business Support and...
```

Help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add `[]` for `list of lists` and then use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([lobbying1], columns=['Organization','Groups'])   
    print (df)

                  Organization        Groups
0  Department of Agric... (35)  Science (35)
                 Organization       Groups
0  Commonwealth Scient... (8)  Science (8)
                Organization       Groups
0  Bureau of Meteorology (4)  Science (4)
                 Organization       Groups
0  Tasmanian Museum an... (1)  Science (1)
                 Organization       Groups
0  Department of Indus... (1)  Science (1)
```

If need one `DataFrame` for all data append `lobbying1` to `data` list and then call [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor out of loop:

```
data = []
for i in webpage_urls:
    wiki2 = i
    page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    # fetching organisations
    data3 = soup.find_all('li', class_="nav-item active")

    lobbying1 = []
    for element in data3:
        lobbying1.append(element.span.get_text())
    data.append(lobbying1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Organization','Groups'])   
print (df)
                  Organization        Groups
0  Department of Agric... (35)  Science (35)
1   Commonwealth Scient... (8)   Science (8)
2    Bureau of Meteorology (4)   Science (4)
3   Tasmanian Museum an... (1)   Science (1)
4   Department of Indus... (1)   Science (1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It exactly matches what I wanted.

Comment: Glad can help. Btw, I very like Australia ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your list `lobbying1` is a list of lists. So you can get a two columns dataframe by simply calling `pd.Dataframe` as follows:

```
lobbying1 = [['Reserve Bank of Aus... (24)', 'Business Support an... (24)'],
['Department of Finance (16)', 'Business Support an... (16)'],
['Department of Agric... (13)', 'Business Support an... (13)']]
df = pd.DataFrame(main_list, columns=['Organization','Groups'])
```

You get this as output

```
>>> df.head() 
                  Organization                       Groups
0  Reserve Bank of Aus... (24)  Business Support an... (24)
1   Department of Finance (16)  Business Support an... (16)
2  Department of Agric... (13)  Business Support an... (13)
>>>
```